# "Auth error from APNS or Web Push Service" FirebaseAdmin SDK C#

Tags: c#, .net, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an application where I need to generate push notifications to individual users based on application permissions.  I have an Angular frontend using Firebase Cloud Messaging to generate and store
token for the user to my server via an API call.  The web front end is the only implementation, so in the firebase console it has a single Web App and no IOS or Android config.  I've set up FirebaseAdmin SDK for C# according to the [Official Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#c) and an attempting to generate multicast messages to the device tokens Ive selected based on a query.  When I catch it in debugger it shows that the call is receiving failure response "Auth error from APNS or Web Push Service".  My Implementation looks like this on the Server side:

```
        FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
        {
            Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("path/to/refreshToken.json"),
            ProjectId = settings.ProjectId,
        });

        var message = new MulticastMessage()
        {
            Tokens = firebaseTokens,
            Data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { "Message", body },
                { "Title", title },
            },
        };

        var result = await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendEachForMulticastAsync(message);
```

The json token I am using is for a service account that has Firebase Service Management Service Agent.  I thought maybe its a permissions issue but I tried a few different combinations and the result seems the same.  Any ideas are appreciated, I've been stuck on this for a while.

**Update**: I tried generating new key for the FirebaseAdmin account and switching to that account instead of service account and I still get the same error.

**Update**: After comment suggestion I have tried catching the defaultInstance in debugger.  I had tried before and upon first glance it appeared to be instantiated but I took a closer look and many of the properties look to be null.  It is getting the App name but perhaps the file isn't being targeted correctly.  Will update once I can confirm.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try getting the path like this and pass the fullPath to GoogleCredential.FromFile ? Also please check if FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance is null. In C# sdk, DefaultInstance is static and you should only be creating it if it is null to protect yourself from some very hard to find bugs down the path and to avoid any memory leakage issues.

```
  string relativeFilePath = "~/app_readme/serviceAccountKey.json";
  string fullPath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(relativeFilePath);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I am doing this all locally in debugger but getting the path for the file by right clicking the file in Visual Studio and selecting "copy path" so the path is the absolute path that looks like this "C:\\Users\\User1\\repos\\thisRepo\\project\\firebasecred-adsfasdfadf.json".

Comment: I tried catching FirebaseMessage.DefaultInstance as you suggested and its instantiating to the correct type but if I drill into the properties MessagingClient seems to have a lot of null values.  But for restPath it shows the name of the project in the URL so I think its not entirely broke?  I think we're onto something!

Comment: Have you uploaded the correct APNS key as well as the team id and key ID  to the cloud messaging in firebase console? This error can also be generated due to that. If just using for web application, have you generated a web push certificate in fcm console?

Comment: I dont have any APNs because I dont have an IOS app, but I have generated the web push certificate in the FCM console and that value is being used in the getToken() method on the server.  I think I might see the problem now.  It should also be used in the getMessaging() method as well, no?

Comment: I see now that on the client side its showing that Notification permission is "denied".  Going to dig a bit deeper and will update if I find the answer.  I know it was working at some point because I have tokens saved to the server and it only saves when its successfully granted.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further examination I found that the token permission was "denied".  To resolve this issue I rewrote the handling for expired tokens on the client.  This looks something like this:

```
if (Notification.permission === 'denied') {
  this.clearToken();
  Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
    // If the user accepts, let's create a notification
    if (permission === 'granted') {
      // Note - this is my method that saves to the server side
      this.notifyme();
    }
  });


clearToken() {
  deleteToken(getMessaging());
}
```

In conjunction with that I rewrote the server side so that if it detects a token is invalid it will flag a Boolean value to mark it as invalidated and "soft-delete" it.